# Sharing a document doesn't share the script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets document with a bunch of script attached. I view and edit that script using Tools > Script Editor. This script also adds a new menu to the toolbar using the onOpen function.

If I share the document with a colleague, she sees the new menu and can run scripts in that menu, but Tools > Script Editor is disabled for her.

I'd like anyone with access to the document to also see the script. Do I need to create an add-on or something instead?

Comment: did you give her edit rights ?

Comment: Yes, she has edit rights.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in Google [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/collaborating#sharingByInheritance), document bounded scripts inherit the sharing properties from their container.

(A few years ago it was not the case but even very old documents have all been updated).

If the behavior you describe can be repeatedly reproduced then you are most probably facing a bug and should report it to the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

In the mean time try to make a copy of it and share it with the same user to see what happens.

A similar issue occured to me a while ago and unsharing/resharing the doc solved the issue. Worth trying...